# Best practice to obtain Lavavel 4.2 Environment

Tags: php, laravel-4, environment-variables

In a Laravel 4.2 framework I've created my own psr-4 php classes under app/mypackages.

Within one of those classes I'd like to check the environment like this:

```
    $environment = Application::environment();
    or
    $environment = Cache::get('environment');
```

but neither is working. In the first example I receive the following error.

```
Non-static method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::environment() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

The $app variable is not available in this context. What is best practice to obtain the environment and make the $app instance available to obtain the environment and some environment dependent variables in config folders?

Relatively new with Laravel so any insights much appreciated.

Comment: The missing piece for me was not including: 
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

And for environment variables a global function
    getenv('variablename');
did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. Try these:

```
App::environment()
app()->environment()
app()->env
$GLOBALS['env'] // not recommended - but it is possible
```

Comment: Thanks for those well documented suggestions. The issue that I am having is that in the context of psr-4 classes the "App" or "app" class is out of scope or as the error message says above has "incompatible context."

My thoughts are that I can pass the application variable down through the stack calls until it is needed or somehow make it available some other way. For now I'm going with the pass down method but am curious is there is another way.